# Salesforce Authenticator Issue

Tags: heroku, salesforce, multi-factor-authentication, authenticator

Can someone assist me on my authenticator app? I set it up few months ago and it went well but then I forgot on how to use this app on my mobile phone and deleted the app. I am stuck with **ADD AN ACCOUNT** that sends two phrases, but my verification wants me to input *6-digit verification code*. However, as much as I want to follow the instructions I do not know where to go since I got stuck with add an account. Not to mention, I can't enable backups because it says that I do not have any salesforce accounts to back up.

What should I do. Does Heroku or salesforce have a chat support that can help me access my account?

I tried to install Salesforce Authenticator App on my phone and enabled everything except the phone number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [we literally cannot help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Contact Heroku support. (Note that this is exactly what MFA is supposed to do. If you can't provide a token, you can't log in. In the future I strongly suggest that you configure an alternate MFA source and / or save your recovery codes.)